# Update Google+ account over email

Tags: google-plus

I'ld like to upload images and post text message to my Google+ account over email. Is there a solution available?

Answer (score 2):

No there is not currently a way to do this until the write API for Google+ is available or Google releases it as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IFTTT](http://www.ifttt.com) to automate stuff. You can use your mobile Facebook email to update Facebook after you update Google+. IFTTT will sync your account every 30 minutes (if not every hour).